# iphone objective c core location mapview first timer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

I am brand new to iphone development and am trying to simply make an app that finds your location and displays it in a map by a click of a button.  I think my code is correct, I just am getting an error in my main.m file which is weird.

I get

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); <--ERROR
    }
}
```

the rest of my project simply uses the storyboard to make half the screen a mapview, and like it as an outlet to the ViewController.h, and make a button bellow it linking to the ViewController.h as an action.  I also imported the two library.  and then in my code for the button's action, its this
{

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocation alloc] init];
_locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


[_mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[_mapview setZoomEnabled:YES];
[_mapview setScrollEnabled:YES];
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}};
region.center.latitude = _locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
region.center.longitude = _locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
region.span.latitudeDelta = .007f;
region.span.longitudeDelta = .007f;
[_mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];
[_mapview setDelegate:sender];
```

}

Thanks to all who can help!!

Comment: Actually, that's not weird at all, it's quite common. It doesn't mean that the problem is in your Main file. If you set an exception breakpoint, sometimes it will show you the offending line of code, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the debugger it will probably tell you what caused the error.look at the target debugger for what caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that Xcode falls into main.m when the crash occurs is irrelevant and you should ignore it. The mistake is somewhere else in your code. You should set an Exception Breakpoint to catch the problem when it occurs:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch09.html#_the_xcode_debugger

If you just want to map where the user is, it's simple enough:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch34.html#_map_kit_and_current_location

If you're more interested in playing with Location Manager and learning how get actual numbers on where the user is:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch35.html#_location